# C++ fopen and drag and drop

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why passing arguments to the exe via command line of my program creates the output file as expected while dragging files onto it doesn't.
Looks like when using drag and drop working directory changes but how to prevent changing it

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *Read,*Write;
    char string[256];
    Read=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    fscanf(Read,"%s",&string);
    Write=fopen("File2.txt","w");   
    fprintf(Write,"%s",&string);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: you don't want to prevent the working directory from "changing". it is the working directory of the parent process. instead explicitly pick up the path to the executable's directory (it is not guaranteed that it's part of argv[0], but it can be, otherwise use OS functionality or perhaps Boost filesystem, if it has that).

Comment: @stefan: drag and drop works fine for console programs in Windows, and in *nix there's no subsystem spec (AFAIK). so which OS are you referring to?

Comment: Why on Earth are you using `stdio` instead of `iostream`?

Comment: Cuz i need functions like fprintf,fscanf. As far as i know iostream is only I/O stream not containing file stream. You probably thought fstream. I tried also with fstream and problem is a same.

Comment: Have you tried **printing** the supposed filename? Don't make assumptions, look at the actual input you get.